MatSuffix as host directive
It seems to be impossible to setup matSuffix as a hostDirective.
Angular team lately made all material components standolone, which supposed to fix this issue but I still can't make it working.
@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-suffix',
  template: `
    <mat-icon 
      color="warn"
    >info_outline</mat-icon>
  `,
  hostDirectives: [
    MatSuffix,
    MatTooltip
  ],
  imports: [MatIconModule],
  standalone: true,
  providers: []
})
export class CustomSuffixComponent {
  constructor() {
    const tooltip = inject(MatTooltip);
    tooltip.message = 'test';
  }
}

<mat-form-field>
  ...
  <app-custom-suffix></app-custom-suffix> 
</mat-form-field>

Tooltip seems to be applied correctly, even though I could not setup it's value within hostDirectives and needed to do it in constructor. MatSuffix on the other hand, seems not to be applied at all.
However, this, after removal of suffix host directive, of course works:
<app-custom-suffix matSuffix></app-custom-suffix>

